# Generic filenames to play audio?

Tags: html5-audio

Hi and thanks so much for your help.
I am adding about 600 .mp3 audio files into individual HTML files. I am wondering if there is any code that I can use to look for and play a file extension (.mp3) and not the full file name.

Is it possible for HTML to overlook a file name and just look for the .mp3 extension? If the file name is example.mp3, is there code that will ignore the example and just look for .mp3. This would save me a lot of renaming and recoding.

Here is my current code:

```
<audio id="Audio">
  <source src="filename.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

Thanks in advance for any help at all.
Nate

Comment: Your code isn't showing up.

Comment: sorry, here is the code:   <audio id="Audio">
          <source src="filename.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
      </audio>